# Incompatible Type Error While Implementing a Struct Array

Tags: c, struct, typedef, declaration

I am trying to create a struct array named Record. For this, I used the code below:

```
typedef struct{
  int studentID;
  char studentName[20];
}STUDENT;

typedef struct{
   STUDENT item;
   struct RECORD *link;
}RECORD;

void initializeTable(RECORD *, int);

int main(){
  int i;
  int m;
  RECORD *hashTable;

  printf("Table Size: "); scanf("%d", &m);
  initializeTable(hashTable, m);
}

void initializeTable(RECORD *hashTable, int m){
  int i;
  hashTable = (RECORD *)malloc(m * sizeof(RECORD));
  for(i=0; i<m; i++){
    hashTable[i] = NULL;
  }
}
```

I got this error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘RECORD {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘void *’
 hashTable[i] = NULL;
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: type of `hashTable[i]` is `RECORD`, not pointer. E.g Change to like `hashTable[i] = (RECORD){ .link = NULL};`

Comment: So, can't we assing null to a struct? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Assigning `NULL` to a structure has no meaning. Initialize each member. Also In your approach you can not actually set the initial value to `hashTable` of `main`.

Comment: What would you even want it to do?  The array members are not pointers, they're structures.  Do you want it to try to assign `NULL` to each of `item` and `link`?  It doesn't work that way.  Just assign the fields directly, to whatever you want.

Comment: You are also probably going to have trouble with the `link` field.  It has type `struct RECORD`, but that has never been defined.  When you try to access it, you will likely have trouble.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I will assing null to components of struct. Thanks,

Comment: @TomKarzes Can I handle it by defining struct as same as the first answer?

Comment: Yes, that is the simplest fix for the `struct RECORD` reference.

Comment: You will then run into the next issue, as the value of `hashTable` will be lost when returning from `initializeTable`.

Comment: @alk Yes I noticed that now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct{
   STUDENT item;
   struct RECORD *link;
}RECORD;
```

There are declared two types. The first one is the type that has typedef name `RECORD`. And the second one is incomplete type `struct RECORD` that is declared inside the type `RECORD`. They are two different type.

You should for example declare the structure like

```
typedef struct RECORD{
   STUDENT item;
   struct RECORD *link;
}RECORD;
```

Also this loop

```
  hashTable = (RECORD *)malloc(m * sizeof(RECORD));
  for(i=0; i<m; i++){
    hashTable[i] = NULL;
  }
```

does not make sense because the expression `hashTable[i]` is not a pointer but an object of the type `RECORD`.

Comment: That is one of the problems.  The other is the attempt to assign `NULL` to a structure (not a structure pointer).  That is the error the OP has encountered first.